# Add first part of div, then add last part of div seperatley using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to warp this ul ( shown below ) in a 2 div

```
<ul id="abcd" class="inner"><div>test</div></ul>
```

and i want to get .

```
<div class="sdfasdF">
<div class="nntt">
    <ul id="abcd" class="inner"><div>test</div></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want you to please share what you have tried.

Comment: Browsers may allow it, but the only truly valid child element for `<ul>` is `<li>`

Comment: `$('.nntt').html('<ul id="abcd" class="inner"><li>test</li></ul>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='sdfasdF'><div class='nntt'></div></div>" );
```

Comment: working demo of the .wrap() function, just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/912bqkbg/

Comment: yes it is working on jsfiddle but when i added in to html file it doesnt work .
here is the code which i tried:
<html>

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style>
.nntt {
    background:red;
    padding:10px;
}

.sdfasdF {
    background:blue;
    padding:10px;
}

#abcd {    padding:10px;
    background:pink;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#abcd").wrap( "<div class='nntt'><div class='sdfasdF'></div></div>" );
</script>

<ul id="abcd" class="inner"><div>test</div></ul>


</body>

</html>

Comment: `$(function(){$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='sdfasdF'><div class='nntt'></div></div>" );})` Try this inside your script

Comment: no still not working. i don't know what is happening because it is working on jsfiddle

Comment: now i tried it again in real file so it work but there is one another problem . 
when i am using it with any div id or class it work . but when i am trying with ul it doesn;t work . and 1 thing i am getting ul ( html ) from jquery-ui.js . so is it not working because of jquery-ui?
here is the example of the code i which i want to integrate it : http://jsfiddle.net/enetqz54/21/
you can find ul in result file using (inspect element )

<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1; display: none;"></ul>